# $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\ (\frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2n-1} + \frac{1}{2n-2} + ... + \frac{1}{n+1})$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

what is the value given to this limit?

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\ \bigg(\frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2n-1} + \frac{1}{2n-2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n+1}\bigg)$$

Is it simply 0 because each term tends to 0 and you are just summing up zeros?

Comment: Presumably you mean the limit as $\color{crimson}n\to\infty$. Note that each sum has $n$ terms, of which $\frac1{2n}$ is the smallest, so each sum is at least $n\cdot\frac1{2n}=\frac12$. Thus, the limit cannot be $0$.

Comment: I'm sure that this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note that each term tends to $0$ but the number of terms tends to $\infty$.*

**Hint**. On may write
$$
\frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2n-1} + \frac{1}{2n-2} + ... + \frac{1}{n+1}=\frac1n \cdot \sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{1+\frac{k}{n}}
$$ and recognize a [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Methods).

Comment: Thank you for the link on Riemann sums, I think I will look through this topic.

Comment: @Andy6978 You are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

> **I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that relies on developing an alternative representation of the series of interest.  To that end we proceed.**

---

Note that we can write the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k+n}=\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n-1}+\cdots \frac{1}{n+1}$ as

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k+n}&=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1k\\\\
&=\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1k} - \color{red}{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k}\\\\
&=\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}+\frac{1}{2k}\right)}-\color{red}{ 2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k}}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{2k}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}
\end{align}$$

> **Therefore, the series of interest is the alternating harmonic series.**

---

Next, recalling that the Taylor Series for $\log(1+x)$ is $\log(1+x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}x^k}{k}$, we have $\log(2)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$.  Therefore, we assert that

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k+n}=\log(2)}$$

---

> **NOTE: Evaluating the alternating harmonic series without appealing to Taylor Series**

We can evaluate the alternating harmonic series a number of ways.  Here we proceed by writing

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}\int_0^1 x^{k-1}\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 \sum_{k=1}^n (-x)^{k-1}\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1\frac{1-(-x)^n}{1+x}\,dx\\\\
&=\log(2)-\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 \frac{(-x)^n}{1+x}\,dx
\end{align}$$

For the integral on the right-hand side of the last expression, the even terms monotonically decrease while the odd terms monotonically increase in $n$.  Inasmuch as the absolute value of the integral is bounded as

$$\left|\int_0^1 \frac{(-x)^n}{1+x}\,dx \right|\le \frac{1}{n+1}$$

the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 \frac{(-x)^n}{1+x}\,dx$ exists and is equal to $0$.  In fact, using Leibniz's test, the alternating series converges and therefore, the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 \frac{(-x)^n}{1+x}\,dx$ must exist.

Therefore, we arrive at the value of the series of interest as $\log(2)$ as expected!

Answer (score 2):

By using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), 
we get $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2n-1} + \frac{1}{2n-2} + ... + \frac{1}{n+1})=\ln{2}$.

Comment: Application of the asymptotic expansion of the harmonic series seems to be an excessive use of force here.

Answer (score 2):

For $n>0\;$ and $\;k=n+1,n+2,...2n,$

$$\int_k^{k+1}\frac{dx}{x}\leq \frac{1}{k}\leq \int_{k-1}^k \frac{dx}{x}$$

$\implies$

$$\ln(\frac{2n+1}{n+1})\leq\sum_{n+1}^{2n}\frac 1k\leq \ln(\frac{2n}{n})$$

and the limit is $\ln(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,

\begin{align*}
  1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n} &=
  \ln n+\gamma+\frac{1}{2n}+O\left( \frac{1}{n^2} \right) \\
  \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2n} &=
  \left[ \ln (2n)+\gamma+\frac{1}{2(2n)} \right]-
  \left( \ln n+\gamma+\frac{1}{2n} \right)+
  O\left( \frac{1}{n^2} \right) \\
  &= \ln 2-\frac{1}{4n}+O\left( \frac{1}{n^2} \right)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

More generally,
using
$\frac1{k}
\gt \int_k^{k+1} \frac{dt}{t}
\gt \frac1{k+1}
$,
we have

$\sum_{an}^{bn} \frac1{k}
\gt \sum_{an}^{bn} \int_k^{k+1} \frac{dt}{t}
= \int_{an}^{bn+1} \frac{dt}{t}
=\int_{an}^{bn} \frac{dt}{t}+\int_{bn}^{bn+1} \frac{dt}{t}
$

so

$\sum_{an}^{bn} \frac1{k}-\int_{an}^{bn} \frac{dt}{t}
\gt \int_{bn}^{bn+1} \frac{dt}{t}
\gt \frac1{bn}
$

and

$\sum_{an}^{bn} \frac1{k}
\lt \sum_{an}^{bn} \int_{k-1}^{k} \frac{dt}{t}
= \int_{an-1}^{bn} \frac{dt}{t}
=\int_{an}^{bn} \frac{dt}{t}+\int_{an-1}^{a} \frac{dt}{t}
$

so

$\sum_{an}^{bn} \frac1{k}-\int_{an}^{bn} \frac{dt}{t}
\lt \int_{an-1}^{an} \frac{dt}{t}
\lt \frac1{an-1}
$.

Since
$\int_{an}^{bn} \frac{dt}{t}
=\ln(bn)-\ln(an)
=\ln\frac{b}{a}
$,

$\frac1{bn}
\lt \sum_{an}^{bn} \frac1{k}-\ln\frac{b}{a}
\lt \frac1{an-1}
$

so

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{an}^{bn} \frac1{k}
=\ln\frac{b}{a}
$.

Note that
any fixed number of terms
added or subtracted 
from the ends of
$\sum_{an}^{bn} \frac1{k}
$
will not change the limit
since the sum
will be changed by
at most
$\frac{c}{n}$
where $c$ depends on
$a, b,$
and the number of terms.